# Mirror Linux Systems Running Game Servers And Payment Managing servers

Tags: linux, web-applications, redundancy

I am building a sort of professional hosting service and want to be able to just switch machines if something goes down on one I use AMP which is a web server along with a game hosting server platform as well as whmcs which is kind of a payment processor it manages giving access to servers and when to charge people PayPal does the actual charging of credit cards. this is a web server as well as PHP And MySQL. what can I do to mirror these servers to another?

Refrences-

https://cubecoders.com/AMP

https://www.whmcs.com/tour/

Comment: If you switch *after* something goes down that means you still lose saved status that may be important to your customers. This is probably way too broad to be answered here, as there is both billing information and by nature difficult to replicate game server software at play here.

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to Serverfault.

Your question touches several topics and providing a useful technical answer for your needs would need a lot of assumptions on what availability, data loss, and cost would be acceptable for you.

Because there are lots of things to consider with the setup you describe, there is no straightforward answer.

To give out a few starting points:

- How long is it acceptable for your system to be unavailable?
- How much data is acceptable to be lost?
- Replication/Mirroring is highly application specific. Find out how to perform the task for each application and be aware of the implications.
- High availability can be done in a lot of ways as well, CARP/VRRP, DNS Roundrobin, keepalived/corosync/pacemaker, just to name a few.
- You might also need a load balancer.
- Try to use one system for one application.

Comment: Ideally, my systems would only be down for 3-5 minutes I can't have any data loss. okay ill try to separate functions to separate systems

Comment: Well - there's no such thing as "no data loss". Have a look at RTO/RPO over at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaster_recovery).